# Additional properties or alternative library to achieve buffer functionality

Tags: buffer, turf, react

In a react native app that I am working on, I have a question about as to whether there are additional properties for turfs buffer to make the buffer around a line not form a closed polygon on overlap or is this the expected of buffers.

These are the relevant imports.

```
import * as turf from '@turf/turf'
import { Polyline, Polygon } from 'react-native-maps'
```

This is the buffer logic I am using.

```
const Buffer = ({ line, coordinates }) => {
  const unit = useSelector((state) => state.settings.unit)

  if (!(line.isBufferVisible && line.buffer)) {
    return null
  }

  const lineString = turf.lineString(coordinates.map((item) => [item.longitude, item.latitude]))

  const buffer = turf.buffer(lineString, line.buffer, {
    units: unit === 'imperial' ? 'feet' : 'meters'
  })

  const latLngCoords = buffer.geometry.coordinates[0].map(([longitude, latitude]) => ({
    latitude,
    longitude
  }))

  return <Polygon coordinates={latLngCoords} fillColor={hexToRgba(blue, 0.25)} />
}
```

And this is the logic for creating the line.

```
const SingleLine = memo(({ line, isTappable, onPress, styles, layer }) => {
  const onPressCallback = useCallback(() => {
    onPress(line)
  }, [line])

  const setOfPoints = get(line, 'setOfPoints', [])

  if (isEmpty(setOfPoints)) return null

  return setOfPoints.map((item, index) => {
    if (isEmpty(item)) return null

    return (
      <React.Fragment key={`${layer.id}-${line.id}-${index}`}>
        <Polyline
          lineJoin="round"
          coordinates={item}
          tappable={isTappable}
          onPress={isTappable && onPressCallback}
          zIndex={4}
          {...styles}
        />

        <Buffer line={line} coordinates={item} />
 
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  })
}, isEqual)
```

The current code produces a buffer around a line that "traces" the line that is generated using the provided buffer in turfs.

[image]

When the buffer size is increased to a large enough size it overlaps and creates one polygon which fills the center.

[image]

The expected behaviour is to have a "donut hole in the center" as visualized below:

[image]

Comment: Please do not double-post [Unexpected behaviour when using turf.buffer (in React native project)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/466709/unexpected-behaviour-when-using-turf-buffer-in-react-native-project)

Comment: @Vince other post was closed. Deleted and posted this one after changing post per the comments received.

Comment: No, deleting and reposting attracts downvotes and can cause automated anti-spam defenses to lock out your account. Much better to edit closed post than  create new one. The other post had garnered open votes, just not enough of them

Comment: @Vince did not know! didn't even know it had votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting polygon without a hole because you are using only outer ring `buffer.geometry.coordinates[0]` of the polygon created with the `turf.buffer` method:

```js
const latLngCoords = buffer.geometry.coordinates[0].map(([longitude, latitude]) => ({
  latitude,
  longitude
}))
```

In the case when buffer ends overlap, `turf.buffer` method creates polygon with a hole, which means it has outer and inner ring:

```js
buffer.geometry.coordinates[0]  // outer ring
buffer.geometry.coordinates[1]  //inner ring
```

You have to use both when creating your buffer polygon. Here is an example (created using OpenLayers and turf.js):

[image]

Comment: I can't cast a vote but thank you for your response!  this was the insight/knowledge I needed to solve this problem. Thank you for taking the time to help